# Print special character in assembly bootloader

Tags: assembly, special-characters, bootloader

I want to print characters such as ▀, ▄ and ■ in my assembly bootloader. But when I do it like this:

```
Println:
    lodsb 
    or al, al
    jz complete
    mov ah, 0x0e        
    int 0x10
    jmp Println        
complete:
    call PrintNwL
PrintNwL: 
    mov al, 0
    stosb
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov al, 0x0D
    int 0x10
    mov al, 0x0A 
    int 0x10
        ret
Msg    db    'Message with specia character ■', 0x0
mov si, Msg
call Println
```

The special characters get replaces by weird other characters.
Thank your for your help

Comment: You'll probably have to encode the character using its hex ASCII value (Code page 437 extended ASCII characters) that can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 . As an example this should print the 3 characters you mention. `Msg    db    'Message with specia character',0xDC,' and', 0xDF, ' and', 0xFE, 0x0`

Comment: Check encoding your editor is using for the source file. At these times the utf-8 is de facto standard in any modern OS (on obsolete like MS Win you may encounter different encoding), while you need classic ASCII (actually not classic, that's just 7 bit, but the PC-extended one with VGA special characters. BTW, IIRC, some BIOSes may have slightly different characters for some codes (mostly national characters for local languages), but the graphical squares/frames should work in most of them. If your editor supports directly ASCII encoding, you can write it like that, otherwise use byte values.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Michael Petch and Ped7g for commenting my question.
I tried out both of your advices, and both did work.

Here's the method I used:

- Write the special characters inside the assembly file in plain text (not like Michael Petch suggested)
- Save the file with *DOS encoding* (I use sublime text as text editor)
- Build it with NASM and the characters display in the BIOS