# Character Block is not showing the right output in Turbo Assembler

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm, codepages, codepage-437

I tried to create a fuel pump with only character blocks in strings but when I compiled it using TASM this is the output the dosbox gave to me.

[image: I don't why this is the output since my characters are stored in strings not characters.]

The data that I stored are mostly character blocks some of them are half blocks up and down the most characters I use for this is the full block.

```
.model small
.stack
.data

    fuelpump0 db     "    ▄█████████████████▄$"
    fuelpump1 db     "   █▀                 ▀█$"
    fuelpump2 db     "   █  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  █  ▄▄▄$"
    fuelpump3 db     "   █  █             █  █    ██▄$"
    fuelpump4 db     "   █  █             █  █    ▀██$"
    fuelpump5 db     "   █  █             █  ███▄   █$"
    fuelpump6 db     "   █  █             █  █  ▀▀█ █$"
    fuelpump7 db     "   █  █             █  █    █ █$"
    fuelpump8 db     "   █  ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀  █    █ █$"
    fuelpump9 db     "   █                   █    █ █$"
    fuelpumpa db     "   █                   █    █ █$"
    fuelpumpb db     "   █                   █    █ █$"
    fuelpumpc db     "   █                   █    █ █$"
    fuelpumpd db     "   █                   █    █ █$"
    fuelpumpe db     "   █                   █    █ █$"
    fuelpumpf db     "   █                   █    ▀█▀$"
    fuelpumpg db     " ▄▄█                   █▄▄$"
    fuelpumph db     " █                       █$"
    fuelpumpi db     " █████████████████████████$"

.code
    begin:
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds,ax

        mov dx, offset fuelpumpn
        mov ah,09h                 
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpump1
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpump2
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpump3
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h


        mov dx, offset fuelpump4
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h


        mov dx, offset fuelpump5
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpump6
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpump7
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpump8
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpump9
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpumpa
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpumpb
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpumpc
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpumpd
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpumpe
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpumpf
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpumpg
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpumph
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset fuelpumpi
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        mov ah, 4ch
        int 21h

    end begin
```

I am starting to wonder if my character is not part of ASCII table since they are all part of extended ASCII characters. I hope I can get some hints to solve the problem.

Comment: That looks like you used an utf8 encoding. Switch to plain 8 bit.

Comment: You also need Carriage Returns and Line Feeds to advance from one line to the next.

Comment: Any source to find them?

Comment: The actual characters depend on your codepage and font. See [wikipedia for codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). Make sure not to use utf8.

Comment: Making each line a separate string is a huge waste of code, especially since you're not even using a loop.  Like ecm said, use a CR LF, but use that *instead* of a `$` at the end of each line except the last.  Then a single output-string DOS call will loop over the whole thing.  (You can still use multiple lines in the source code, of course; the DOS call doesn't know or care how the bytes got into memory, just that they're there.)

Comment: I am sorry about that. I am very new to Assembly language and still learning the roots of it. But I am starting to have an affection to this and planned to dive deeper as I progress. About the code, I replaced the character blocks with ASCII Extended keys instead of Code Page 437 and they all worked perfectly. https://imgur.com/a/nHhHKXj

Comment: sort of a duplicate of [Print special character in assembly bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45753369).  That doesn't mention UTF-8, but copy/paste of the source code shows it's using UTF-8 in the form posted to SO.  You could post your own answer to this question, with details to help future readers with the same problem, if you want.

Comment: Also [Printing special (non-Latin) characters in a legacy-BIOS bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66904170) looks like a good canonical duplicate for questions about special characters in bootloaders.  And/or [How to get alpha character (α) in DOS/Asembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67658842) / [8086 Assembly Int 21h and Extended ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12326609)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I solved the problem, it may not be the best solution but here's what I did:

- TASM is able to echo special characters in Extended ASCII Table by just simply typing the decimal values of each special characters like ▐ (222), █ (219), ▀ (223) and ▄ (220). Just make sure they have commas each of them and must not be the inside the quotation marks.
- You can mix both strings and integers in every data string you are storing just make sure you put commas for every strings, and integers and add 13,10 as the return key and "$" to the end.

Comment: Writing the character codes out in decimal or hex is very reasonable, especially if you want to edit the source code with an editor that doesn't easily handle CP437 text files.  It takes source-code encoding out of the equation entirely so the source can be the plain-ASCII subset of UTF-8, at the expense of making source source not "look like" what will be on screen so you need comments.  (Or macro defines for the character shapes.)

Answer (score 1):

The distorted output comes from

- not inserting the necessary newlines
- a mismatch in codepages between your editor and the DOS console

Because your representation of a fuelpump contains a lot of graphics characters, replacing all of these by their correct extended ASCII codes will be rather tedious and will also destroy the nice layout that is self-documentary.
I suggest you replace the different *Block* characters by somewhat similar characters from the lower half of the ASCII character set.

Replace ▀ (223) by ' (39)
Replace █ (219) by | (124)
Replace ▄ (220) by , (44)

Doing so produces next data which still resembles a fuelpump:

```
fuelpump db     "    ,|||||||||||||||||,", 13, 10
         db     "   |'                 '|", 13, 10
         db     "   |  ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,  |  ,,,", 13, 10
         db     "   |  |             |  |    ||,", 13, 10
         db     "   |  |             |  |    '||", 13, 10
         db     "   |  |             |  |||,   |", 13, 10
         db     "   |  |             |  |  ''| |", 13, 10
         db     "   |  |             |  |    | |", 13, 10
         db     "   |  '''''''''''''''  |    | |", 13, 10
         db     "   |                   |    | |", 13, 10
         db     "   |                   |    | |", 13, 10
         db     "   |                   |    | |", 13, 10
         db     "   |                   |    | |", 13, 10
         db     "   |                   |    | |", 13, 10
         db     "   |                   |    | |", 13, 10
         db     "   |                   |    '|'", 13, 10
         db     " ,,|                   |,,", 13, 10
         db     " |                       |", 13, 10
         db     " |||||||||||||||||||||||||", 13, 10, 0
```

Of course, displaying now requires some extra processing, not that it matters!

```
        ...
        mov     si, offset fuelpump
        jmp     Fetch
Subst:  mov     dl, 223   ; TopBlock
        cmp     al, 39    ; SingleQuote
        je      Print
        mov     dl, 219   ; FullBlock
        cmp     al, 124   ; Pipe
        je      Print
        mov     dl, 220   ; BottomBlock
        cmp     al, 44    ; Comma
        je      Print
        mov     dl, al    ; Space (32), Carriage Return (13), Linefeed (10)
Print:  mov     ah, 02h   ; DOS.PrintCharacter
        int     21h
Fetch:  mov     al, [si]
        inc     si
        cmp     al, 0
        jne     Subst
        ...
```